# Properties as a route-level rather than an Exchange-level

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to set a property at the level of a Route, rather than an Exchange. 
As a simplified example, if I wanted to have something like invocation-count or last-invoked-time and check/update it each time the route was triggered, how would I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement that a number of ways.. using a simple Java class as a processor right after the "from", or as an interceptor (use interceptFrom): http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html.

Curiously though.. you should consider using the out-of-the-box Camel metrics. You should be covered by the defaults.